# Use idris elaborator for sandboxed code

Tags: sandbox, idris

I'd like to be able to run untrusted sandboxed code within Idris. Is it possible to use the idris elaborator (or some other method) to reject any untrusted code that:

1. references symbols from outside of a specific set of modules, or
2. is not total

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [su].

Comment: What do you mean by "general computing software"? I'm not talking about hardware here, so I assume my question falls in the second category. I also don't understand what you mean by "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming", and why Idris, which is a programming language, doesn't fall under this exception. I'm talking about using reflection here. Coding with reflection isn't programming? I'm seriously confused. I also checked out superuser.com. That is not a site which addresses questions about using programming languages. I don't think I'd get much help there.

Comment: It seemed you were asking about Idris configuration or tools especially given that your questions has no code.

Comment: The Idris Elaborator allows you to build code within the language itself. It is mostly used for macros, but I'm trying to repurpose it for self-modifying code, basically. I'm probably going to have to modify the Idris compiler itself, but I wanted to see if anyone knew more about the elaborator, since I'm very new to it. I know it can construct code on the fly, so it seemed like a good place to start.

Comment: That's a very broad question that could have many opinionated answers so isn't really a good fit for SO.  Do some more research on Elaborator on the wider net to see if anyone has done what you want to do.  If not, you'll have to learn more about what it can and can't do then try to develop some code to do it.  When the code breaks, come back to SO.